Unexpected Landscape Orientation of iPhone MOV Video When Played on PC
I'm facing an issue with the orientation of MOV video files exported from an iPhone.
When viewing the properties of these videos on a PC, the frame width (1920) is larger than the frame height (1080), even though the videos were shot in portrait mode (vertical). Here's what I've checked so far:
The videos play in portrait orientation on the iPhone itself.
When transferred to a PC, they display as landscape in the file properties, but some video players still play them in portrait orientation.
There has been no editing or processing of the videos; they are as exported from the iPhone.
iPhone 11 Pro Max on iOS 17.4 Beta
Transferedto PC via cabel
"VLC Player" and the default one plays the video with the proper orientation
Here is a sample of the video file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1P0d-dUQqd3ern0zfKZXP5UF-oBMHzO3y/view?usp=sharing
Frame width: 1920
Frame height: 1080





Has anyone faced a similar issue, or does anyone know how to resolve this so that the video properties reflect the correct orientation? Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

So as I have understood, Apple uses Orientation property to define the proper orientation.
So they do not rotate the video each time you want to change the orientation, cos' they are just rendering it the proper way.


Yes.  Phones and other digital cameras doesn't save the video (or photos) in Portrait mode.  It is always saved as Landscape (width longer than height).   There is a sensor in the camera which detects the current orientation of the camera and saves that into the metadata when it writes the file. It is then up to the viewing program to properly rotate the video/image.
